# CSS3 Select Replacement bug with jquery1.7

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

On this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cYrqY/64/

I can't figure out why the First item of the list is not showing. It normally works on older version of jQuery but the latest has changed something.

It is a multiple Select box and each one has different content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
if(i==select.attr('selectedIndex')){
    selectBox.html(option.text());
}
```

in 1.6+ you need to use `prop`:

```
if(i==select.prop('selectedIndex')){
    selectBox.html(option.text());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cYrqY/70/

Comment: Good eyes, just figured that one out!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, so to speak, atleast it's not a jQuery bug.

You're returning `option.data('html-text')`, this means the option needs a `data-html-text` attribute, wich the first one does not have. Also it has `data-skip` set, wich should be removed.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cYrqY/69/)

Comment: Change the jquery version to 1.5 in the fiddle and see how it works.  That isn't what he's trying to do.

Comment: Exactly works with the previews version of Jquery but I need it to work with 1.7..